# get_or_create() question

Tags: python, django-models, save

From the official documentation I can't understand what is default parameter.

```
obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
                  defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)}
```

Does it mean that it will look for fields which match both `John` and `Lennon` parameter and birthday will just insert? Can I use something else instead of defaults?

And what method should I use to clean all fields in table (models)?

It give me FileField error can not resolve keyword default in field

So I need look for fiels, if i found it - update datas. If i didn't find it I have to crate new field... But, as I understud, It won't update me default fields when finde present fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite obvious - if `get_or_create` finds queried object, the `defaults` keword does nothing. But if it creates object, then instance stored in `obj` has `birthday` field (in your example) filled with according value. You can pass any dictionary as `defaults`, as long as its keys are valid field names for model you're querying.

To clean the whole table, you should use something like:

```
Model.objects.all().delete()
```

which is equivalent of:

```
DELETE FROM app_model WHERE True;
```

To set some field in every object ( some column in every row ), there is `update()` method:

```
Model.objects.all().update( some_field = "" )
```

which translates to:

```
UPDATE app_model SET `some_field` = '' WHERE True;
```

My sql is a bit rusty, but I believe it goes like that, more or less.

Comment: So It not fit me. Becose I need look for field with proper name. If I found it i need to update ather fields, but if i did not find it i have to create it end write all fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.get_or_create) django documentation for a more  detailed explanation on get_or_create method. In short, it first tries to get with the first_name and last_name provided, if not it instantiates and saves a new object in which case the default dictionary is used. And the return value is the corresponding object and True/False whether a new object was created or not.

Comment: It give me FileField error can not resolve keyword default in field

Comment: It should be defaults, not default (notice the lack of 's')

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything. default if you not set anything.

Comment: So what meen this dictionary? what it will do whis paramenters which is inside?

Comment: this is called Keyword param, it will match the calling param to the function called by the param name.